# Facebook Login SDK for Web (their basic, original example!) not calling callback at first connection

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I spent all day on this, to no avail.
 I am not talking about an obscure, crazy, unstable, pre-alpha build of some node.js thing...
I simply cut&pasted the code from here, the OFFICIAL FB page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

It works, I see the login button, can login&logout, see who else is using my app, if I logout the callback gets called...
but it looks like the "connected" callback is called ONLY if I reach the page when I am already logged in FB.
If I click on the Login button and do the login, it works (I can also see "who else" is using my app as I said, for example) but no callback is called. I need to refresh the page and then the callback is called.

Furthermore, in the console I can see this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:90
```

And just for information, the "line 90" is simply too long and almost unreadable to be posted here, but it makes me wonder that you can see "UserAgent_DEPRECATED" at the beginning. I am using the latest official Chrome build.

```
__d("sdk.ErrorHandling",["sdk.feature","ManagedError","sdk.Runtime","sdk.Scribe","UserAgent_DEPRECATED","wrapFunction"],function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){var m=g('error_handling',false),n='';function o(u){var v=u._originalError;delete u._originalError;j.log('jssdk_error',
```

Of course, there is no error if and when I refresh the page...

UPDATE: Same behavior with latest Firefox. Same error in the console too, even though it doesn't redirect me to a source code line, it just opens the whole source code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use == to compare (or even ===, if you want to compare types). a single = is for assignment.

Comment: Sorry I do not get it. Where? In which line? Thanks. LLAP.

Comment: the js error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" is always caused by comparison or assignement syntax.
LLAP to you :)